# How to set the correct height for a UIDatePicker?

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

How do I set the height of a datePicker correctly across the range of different iOS devices? I can get the width from the width of the window but not the height.

Here's my code:

```
let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
let width = app_delegate.window!.frame.width
let size = CGSize(width: width, height: 300)
let frame = CGRect(origin:origin , size: size)
birthday.inputView = UIDatePicker(frame: frame)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing `Bounds` and `Frame`. `Frame` is a rectangle describing the superview. `Bounds` is that of the local rectangle.

If you want the height and width of the device's screen you need to use the bounds of:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

If you want the height to be a maximum of 300 (as in your example) you can use a computed variable like:

```
let height : CGFloat = {
    if size.height > 300.0 {
        return 300.0
    } else {
        return size.height
    }
}()
```

Comment: I would like the height of the picker to be appropriate to the device. If it's a Plus, a 7 or a SE the picker will be different heights. How do i get the correct minimum height?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. The default height for a DatePicker is 216 points. This is the same on a 4", 4.7" and a 5.5" device. If you want the DatePicker height to be relative to a fraction of the screen height you can use a computed var to set the frame's height. For example with: self.view.bounds.height * some_multiplier

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses Keyboard at some time, then you can get Height of the Keyboard and apply that value to be the height of your DatePicker, otherwise you can say

```
datePickerHeight = view.frame.height / 3
```

to get a good appealing height. So if you use a bigger or smaller phone, it will do the maths by itself.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `sizeToFit` for calculate its own size:

```
let size = datePicker.sizeThatFits(.zero)
print("height:", size.height) // height: 315.0
```